# Java caching System (JCS): Loading 300 MB Data into cache taking 2-3 hours

Tags: jcs

Scenario:
I have 2-3 java hash maps (80lack entries: Around 300MB). I am loading it into JCS disk cache. It takes 2-3 hours to load it!
Here is the code for loading the data!
package example;

public class Singleton 
{

```
private static Singleton single_instance = null; 
public JCS cache_bestfeatures;
public JCS cache_tposmap;
public JCS cache_tnegmap; 
public JCS cache_tnetmap;    
public JCS cache_pos;
public JCS cache_neg; 
public JCS cache_net;
public JCS cache_total;    
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Singleton() throws CacheException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    CompositeCacheManager ccm = CompositeCacheManager.getUnconfiguredInstance();
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("jcs.default", "DC");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.default.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes.MaxLifeSeconds", "21600");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes.IdleTime", "1800");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes.IsSpool", "true");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes.IsRemote", "true");
    props.put("jcs.default.elementattributes.IsLateral", "true");

    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures", "DC_BestFeatures");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.bestfeatures.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");

    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_BestFeatures", "org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheFactory");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_BestFeatures.attributes", "org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_BestFeatures.attributes.DiskPath", "/home/alethe/workspace/example/src/example");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_BestFeatures.attributes.MaxPurgatorySize", "10000");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_BestFeatures.attributes.MaxKeySize", "10000000");

    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_general", "org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheFactory");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_general.attributes", "org.apache.jcs.auxiliary.disk.indexed.IndexedDiskCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_general.attributes.DiskPath", "/home/alethe/workspace/example/src/example");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_general.attributes.MaxPurgatorySize", "10000");
    props.put("jcs.auxiliary.DC_general.attributes.MaxKeySize", "10000000");        

    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap", "DC_general");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.tposmap.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");

    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap", "DC_general");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnegmap.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");        

    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap", "DC_general");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.tnetmap.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");

    props.put("jcs.region.pos", "DC_general");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.pos.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");

    props.put("jcs.region.neg", "DC_general");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.neg.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");        

    props.put("jcs.region.net", "DC_general");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.net.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");        
    props.put("jcs.region.net.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");                

    props.put("jcs.region.total", "DC_general");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.cacheattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.cacheattributes.MaxObjects", "1");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.cacheattributes.MemoryCacheName", "org.apache.jcs.engine.memory.lru.LRUMemoryCache");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.cacheattributes.UseMemoryShrinker", "false");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.cacheattributes.MaxMemoryIdleTimeSeconds", "3600");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.cacheattributes.ShrinkerIntervalSeconds", "60");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.cacheattributes.MaxSpoolPerRun", "500");
    props.put("jcs.region.total.elementattributes", "org.apache.jcs.engine.ElementAttributes");        
    props.put("jcs.region.total.elementattributes.IsEternal", "true");                        



    ccm.configure(props);
    cache_bestfeatures = JCS.getInstance( "bestfeatures" );        
    cache_tposmap = JCS.getInstance( "tposmap" );        
    cache_tnegmap = JCS.getInstance( "tnegmap" );        
    cache_tnetmap = JCS.getInstance( "tnetmap" );        
    cache_pos = JCS.getInstance( "pos" );        
    cache_neg = JCS.getInstance( "neg" );        
    cache_net = JCS.getInstance( "net" );        
    cache_total = JCS.getInstance( "total" );

    HashSet<Pair<String, String>> bestfeatures_tmp = new HashSet<Pair<String, String>> ();
    ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float> pos_tmp = new ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float>();
    ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String,String>, Float> neg_tmp = new ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String,String>, Float>();        
    ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String,String>, Float> net_tmp = new ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String,String>, Float>();        
    HashMap<String, Float> tposMap_tmp = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    HashMap<String, Float> tnegMap_tmp = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    HashMap<String, Float> tnetMap_tmp = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float> total_tmp = new HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float>();        
    String train_folder_path = "/home/alethe/Desktop/JCS/TrainingParam/";

    int j = 0;
    System.out.println("Here");
    ObjectInputStream object_best_feature = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream( train_folder_path +  "best_features.tmp"));
    bestfeatures_tmp = (HashSet<Pair<String, String>>) object_best_feature.readObject();        
    System.out.println("Top features loaded with count : "+ bestfeatures_tmp.size());
    Iterator<Pair<String, String>> iterator = bestfeatures_tmp.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Pair<String, String> p  = iterator.next();
        cache_bestfeatures.put(p, true);
        System.out.println(j + "  ");
        j = j + 1;
        iterator.remove();
    }
    object_best_feature.close();


    System.out.println("Here");
    ObjectInputStream object_tpos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(train_folder_path +  "tposMap.tmp"));
    tposMap_tmp = (HashMap<String, Float>) object_tpos.readObject();        
    System.out.println("tposMap : "+ tposMap_tmp.size());

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Float>> iter = tposMap_tmp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        Map.Entry<String,Float> entry = iter.next();
        cache_tposmap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        iter.remove();
    }
    object_tpos.close();


    System.out.println("Here");
    ObjectInputStream object_tneg = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(train_folder_path +  "tnegMap.tmp"));
    tnegMap_tmp = (HashMap<String, Float>) object_tneg.readObject();        
    System.out.println("tnegMap : "+ tnegMap_tmp.size());

    iter = tnegMap_tmp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        Map.Entry<String,Float> entry = iter.next();
        cache_tnegmap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        iter.remove();
    }
    object_tneg.close();

    System.out.println("Here");
    ObjectInputStream object_tnet = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(train_folder_path +  "tnetMap.tmp"));
    tnetMap_tmp = (HashMap<String, Float>) object_tnet.readObject();        
    System.out.println("tnetMap : "+ tnetMap_tmp.size());

    iter = tnetMap_tmp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        Map.Entry<String,Float> entry = iter.next();
        cache_tnetmap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        iter.remove();
    }
    object_tnet.close();

    System.out.println("Here");
    ObjectInputStream object_pos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(train_folder_path +  "pos.tmp"));
    pos_tmp = (ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float>) object_pos.readObject();     
    System.out.println("pos : "+ pos_tmp.size());
    int i = 0;

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, Float>> iter2 = pos_tmp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) 
    {
        Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, Float> entry = iter2.next();
        cache_pos.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        iter2.remove();
        System.out.println(i + "  ");
        i = i + 1;
    }
    object_pos.close();

    i = 0;
    System.out.println("Here");     
    ObjectInputStream object_neg = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(train_folder_path +  "neg.tmp"));
    neg_tmp = (ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float>) object_neg.readObject();     
    System.out.println("Neg : "+ neg_tmp.size());
    iter2 = neg_tmp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) 
    {
        Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, Float> entry = iter2.next();
        cache_neg.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        iter2.remove();
        System.out.println(i + "  ");
        i = i + 1;
    }
    object_neg.close();

    i = 0;
    System.out.println("Here");
    ObjectInputStream object_net = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(train_folder_path +  "net.tmp"));
    net_tmp = (ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float>) object_net.readObject();     
    System.out.println("Net : "+ net_tmp.size());
    iter2 = net_tmp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) 
    {
        Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, Float> entry = iter2.next();
        cache_net.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        iter2.remove();
        System.out.println(i + "  ");
        i = i + 1;
    }
    object_net.close();

    int z = 0;
    System.out.println("Here");     
    ObjectInputStream object_total = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(train_folder_path +  "total.tmp"));
    total_tmp = (HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Float>) object_total.readObject();       
    for(Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, Float> entry : total_tmp.entrySet())
    {
        cache_total.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        System.out.println(z + "  ");
        z = z + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("total : "+ total_tmp.size());
    total_tmp.clear();
    object_total.close();

}
public static Singleton getInstance() throws CacheException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    if (single_instance == null)
        single_instance = new Singleton();

    return single_instance;
}
```

}

Question:
Why is it taking 2-3 hours? Is there anything I am setting wrong in JCS configuration?